# Get Original Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, fft

I have the following matrix `A`:

```
 1   2   3   4 
 5   6   7   8
 9  10  11  12 
13  14  15  16
```

Now I performed the following operations on the said matrix:

```
B = fft2(A);
amp = abs(B);
amp_norm = amp/max(max(amp));
p = angle(B);
p_norm = p/pi;
```

Now, if I have the matrices `amp_norm` and `p_norm` and do not know how these two matrices are obtained from the original matrix, then how can we get back the original matrix `A`?
5-10% error is OK.

Comment: If you literally have  no information, there is no way of getting that matrix back other than infinite hit and trials

Comment: This might be more of a math question

Comment: The problem in finding `amp` from `amp_norm`. Rest is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in reconstructing your original matrix `A` comes from the fact that you are normalizing your `amp` matrix. Unless you save your `max(max(amp))` value somewhere, that signal information is lost forever.

Given `p` and `amp`, your original matrix `A` can be reconstructed as follows:

```
B_orig = amp .* exp(p .* 1i);
A_orig = round(real(ifft2(B_orig)));
```

Given `p_norm` and `amp_norm`, instead, you can rebuild the original `p` but not `amp`... unless the aforementioned normalization factor is stored somewhere:

```
k = 136; % the original max(max(amp)) value
p_orig = p_norm .* pi;
amp_orig = amp_norm .* k;
B_orig = amp_orig .* exp(p_orig .* 1i);
A_orig = round(real(ifft2(B_orig)));
```